# Visual Studio shows blank page when web application is run

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I've had an occasional issue with my laptop where the power instantly cuts out - without the machine shutting down properly.  This happened a couple of times yesterday while I was working on a project in VS 2013.  Since then when I try to run the project the browser loads and the name of the start up page appears in the url box but it just shows a blank page.

Before, the page loading icon in the Chrome tab would swirl for a while as it was loading, but now it hardly does that at all, as if it's not even trying to load the page.

Some extra info:

- I tried setting a different starting page - same result.
- I put a break point in the page load code - it doesn't get hit.
- If I view the source of the blank it is completely empty, not even
   tags
- Other projects seem to work find still.
- I'm using VS 2013 on Windows 7.
- Tried deleting the temp asp.net files
  (c/windows/microsoft.net/framework64/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET
  Files) but curiously this folder is already empty - I'm sure this is
  what I've done with problem projects before - although I've never
  seen this particular problem.
- I'm running on IISExpress and have tried all browsers and running without debugging with the same result.

Has anyone seen this problem before? Any ideas??

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried launching the site in another installed browser? Does running without debugging (ctrl F5) work? Are you hosting the website in IIS or IISExpress?

Comment: Yes, tried in Chrome, FF and IE, all the same result. Same for ctrl F5. It's running on IISExpress. Thanks

Comment: Maybe create a new solution and copy the files from the broken solution step by step? Could be one of those vague problems where you never actually figure out the cause... Good luck :)

Comment: REALLY hoped it wouldn't come to that! but thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Solved it by adding a break point at **Application_Error** function in **Global.asax.cs**. Then I was able to see the real problem. It was because of some conflicting dlls.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem as well. Suddenly when I launch my MVC web application from Visual Studio 2013, the browser comes up and the app is running, but the browser displays blank, no url and does not even try to load the page. In Visual Studio, none of the Script Documents are loaded either.

Simply by setting a breakpoint in Global.asax.cs, Application_start, everything went back to normal, problem solved.